# How to handle the How to return the response from an AJAX call questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

Every single day we are encountering 10+ question of the same type, dealing with how to handle the result of an asynchronous ajax request(a possible duplication of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)) in SO, the same exists for event delegation for dynamic elements also.

How should we handle it?

Right now I don't have a consistent approach - Sometimes I answer the question otherwise mark it as duplicate

*Note: It will be great if somebody can pullout a stats saying how many other questions are marked as duplicate of the said question*

Comment: Yeah, this is exhausting... Thank goodness for the canonical post that Felix put out there

Comment: Per the number of questions marked as a duplicate, there are 464 [linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/14220321?lq=1) and most of them look to be duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We keep closing them as duplicates. Occasionally, *also* posting a helpful quick answer to help the OP get started is okay. But if it's a duplicate, always vote to close too. If it's really low quality, downvote, and perhaps edit or vote to delete. There's nothing we can do to stop those questions from being posted.

I am aware the above paragraph is simplifying things, and in fact I asked myself this very same question recently (I agree with you, those question are annoying). Sometimes, it's difficult to classify the question as a duplicate of that reference post, usually because:

- The question is not about a "direct" ajax request (i.e., a vanilla-js `XMLHttpRequest`, or a jQuery `$.ajax` or similar), but about a third-party API "disguising" the ajax operation under a more specific name (think of Google Maps API geocoding methods).

or:

- The question is not exactly about *returning* a value from a callback, but about some similar operation such as assigning a value to a global variable from within the callback, and expecting the variable to be populated before the callback actually runs (because in source-code order it looks like it already ran).

In both cases, the OP might not understand that the reference answers address what he's asking about, although we know that the underlying problem is the same: the OP is unaware of how asynchronous JavaScript operations work, and sometimes they don't even know the basics about HTTP requests. Frequently, it's unclear to us what exactly the OP is missing.

That's why I believe most such questions deserve at least a link to that reference post: both top answers there do a very good job in explaining the basic concepts. I also believe that closing as a duplicate of that question is adequate, unless you know a closer duplicate to point to. In cases where we feel a simple link/close vote is not enough, we can add a comment or short answer to help the asker understand why we are pointing him there.

If the OP is really interested in learning the *why* behind their problem, the reference answers should help a lot; and if the OP is not interested in that, should we be interested in helping?